# Why does this class method call in mql5 give an unexpected token error on compilation?

Tags: oop, mql5

When I try to compile the following code:

```
struct pricePoint{
   double price;
   datetime time;
public:
   pricePoint(){
      price = 0;
      time = 0;
   }
};

class CMktStruct{
   pricePoint h[2];
   pricePoint l[2];
public:
   CMktStruct(void);
   void PrintStruct(){PrintFormat("HiPrice1=%.5f HiTime1=%i; HiPrice2=%.5f HiTime2=%i: LoPrice1=%.5f LoTime1=%i; LoPrice2=%.5f LoTime2=%i",h[0].price,h[0].time,h[1].price,h[1].time,l[0].price,l[0].time,l[1].price,l[1].time);};
};

CMktStruct::CMktStruct(void){
   l[0].price = DBL_MAX;
   l[1].price = DBL_MAX;  
}

CMktStruct ms();
ms.PrintStruct();
```

I get an `'ms' - unexpected token, probably type is missing?` error.

Commenting out the last line leads to the code compiling with no problem.

I want to print the Market Structure as defined (after initialisation and without further modification this should give "HiPrice1=0.00000 HiTime1=0; HiPrice2=0.00000 HiTime2=0: LoPrice1=1.79769e+308 LoTime1=0; LoPrice2=1.79769e+308 LoTime2=0")

Answer (score 0):

You cant execute a method in global scope...
Try this:

```
struct pricePoint{
   double price;
   datetime time;
public:
   pricePoint(){
      price = 0;
      time = 0;
   }
};

class CMktStruct{
   pricePoint h[2];
   pricePoint l[2];
public:
   CMktStruct(void);
   void PrintStruct(){PrintFormat("HiPrice1=%.5f HiTime1=%i; HiPrice2=%.5f HiTime2=%i: LoPrice1=%.5f LoTime1=%i; LoPrice2=%.5f LoTime2=%i",h[0].price,h[0].time,h[1].price,h[1].time,l[0].price,l[0].time,l[1].price,l[1].time);};
};

CMktStruct::CMktStruct(void){
   l[0].price = DBL_MAX;
   l[1].price = DBL_MAX;  
}

CMktStruct ms();


int OnInit()
  {
// Executing the method inside localscope
   ms.PrintStruct();

   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
```

Comment: Many thanks - still getting my head round OOP as opposed to my traditional style of coding (haphazard and self taught!)